# My Controller not extending

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have recently upgraded my codeigniter version from 1.7 to 2.1. However, I am struggling to extend my my_controller class, previously it was working fine when put in the app->libraries folder.

With CI instructions I have moved it too app -> core directory, the code is as follows:

```
    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    var $data=array();
    var $secured=false;
    var $area="user";
    function my_Controller(){

         parent::__construct();




        // loading libraries etc
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');                 
        $this->load->helper('common');
```

[..]

And in the config file I have added the following line of code as demonstrated from this tutorial:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

```
    /*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Native Auto-load
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| 
| Nothing to do with cnfig/autoload.php, this allows PHP autoload to work
| for base controllers and some third-party libraries.
|
*/
function __autoload($class)
{
 if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
 {
  @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
 }
}
```

Yet I am still getting the following PHP error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MY_Controller' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\latestCI\application\controllers\home.php on line 5

Any idea why this is not working, thanks

Edit:

Seemed to have gotten it to work. Basically MY_Controller has to follow this structure:

```
 <?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
//constructor code here
}

//Custom functions here
}


?>
```

Otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: have you tried it moving in to libraries folder?

Comment: yep this was the first thing I did.

Comment: try removing the lines you added in config file and check

Comment: Still doesn't work. :(

Comment: some bad practice in the code. use `__construct()` instead of `function my_Controller()`. use `public` instead of `var`. for readibility, explicitely call the functions `public/private/protected` these wont solve your issues but it is time we should adapt to new desgins and syntaxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to place your `MY_Controller.php` file (captialization is important!) under `application/core/`. This folder is introduced (among others) with codeiginiter version 2.

When in doubt, check where the original class's file located under the `system/` directory and mirror that under `application/`. 
 So if the `CI_Controller.php` is under `system/core/` then the `MY_Controller` (which extends `CI_Controller`) should go to `application/core`.

Comment: Right MY_Controller.php (with caps is in application core) and CI_Controller.php is in system/core/ it is still throwing the same error. My php version is 5.3.19 could this be affecting it?

Comment: Seem to have fixed it, the problem was the syntax. It did not like function my_Controller(){